# PHP/MySql merge same value with different data's separated respectively

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a testing on event booking. I have created a VIEW, merging three tables(stage_info, show_info & show_time_info).

Table1:

```
stage_info  columns(stage_id,stage_name)
```

Table2:

```
show_info  columns(show_id,show_name,show_desc)
```

Table3:

```
show_time_info  columns(show_time_id, show_time)
```

table VIEW name: `show_time_view`

final VIEW table look like this:

```
evet_shw_tm_id  stage_id  show_id  show_time_id  show_name  stage_name   show_time
       1         1         2          1              UUU        xyz        10:00
       5         1         2          2              UUU        xyz        11:45
```

Here `stage_id`, `stage_name` & `show_id` will be respectively same.

I want something to looks like this in Front-end:

```
Stage Name     Show Name               Timings         
 xyz               UUU                10:00, 11:45
```

In this above table user can click the time and they will be directed to another page according to the time they select.

Hope I explained what i actually want. Alternative solution is also considerable.

Comment: [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) ?